# Text color changes back after resizing bootstrap

Tags: html, css, fonts, media-queries

I'm working on a small project which involves pricing tables (http://laurensvandijk.com/as/diensten.html)

There are two different text colors I'd like to use, a lighter color for all the features that aren't included, and a darker color for the features that are included.

I've tried using this code:

```css
.nofeature {
        color: #cccccc;
    }
```

```html
<p class="nofeature"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        Verzorging kunststof</p>
```

Whenever I resize this page to tablet or mobile view, the lighter font color (with the X in front of the text) changes back to the darker, normal text color. I have looked in to the bootstrap.css file but I haven't been able to find a proper solution.

Comment: I think bootstrap it's overwriting your css style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just watched your CSS `prijstabel.min.css`

You have set the `.nofeature` rule in `@media (min-width: 1200px)` wich means it applies only when you have a width of at least 1200px.

Just set your `.nofeature` rule at the end of your css, in no @media rule

Answer (score 0):

Because you have written `.nofeature` in `@media (min-width:1200px)` and its desktop view only, so it is not applied in mobile and tablet.

Use this class out of `@media`, then it will applied in all screen.